# Wordpress/slick.js center mode doesn't show my images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I'm trying to combine slick.js with an ACF gallery in Wordpress.
The only problem is my images are not showing up. [example](http://www.goedgevonden.net/blog)
Does anyone know whats causing this?
I've been looking for hours now and can't seem to find the solution, guess I'm missing something...

My code

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 center">
<?php query_posts( 'cat=2' ); ?>
   <?php
   if( have_posts() ):
       while( have_posts() ): the_post(); $i++; ?>

<div class="single-post">


<?php $images = get_field('gallery'); if( $images ): ?> <!– This is the gallery filed slug –>

<div class=”slider”>

<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?> <!– This is your image loop –>

<div>

<img src=”<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>” alt=”<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>” />

</div>

<!– Image Slider Code –>

<?php endforeach; ?> <!– This is where the image loop ends –>

</div>

<?php endif; ?> <!– This is where the gallery loop ends –>                  


         <p class="entry-title"><?php the_field('post_titel'); ?></p>
       <p class="metadata">  <?php the_field('post_datum'); ?>
       <span class="metagap">  <?php the_field('post_categorie'); ?></span></p>
    <p class="twocol"><?php the_field('post_tekst', false, false); ?></p>

</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
   <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                  <?php get_footer(); ?>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    speed: 500,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 1
        }
    }]
});
});
```

css

```
   .slick-center .slide-h3{
    color: #FFF;
  }

  .slider{
    width: 600px;  
    height:150px;
    margin: 20px auto;    
    text-align: center;
  }
  .slide-h3{
    margin: 10% 0 10% 0;
    padding: 40% 20%;
    background: #008ed6;
  }
  .slider div{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .slick-slide{
    opacity: .6;
  }

  .slick-center{
    display: block;
    max-width: 10% !important;
    max-height:20% !important;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a problem with double quotes:

```
<img src="”4”" alt="”4”">
```

You are using the "fancy curly" double quotes instead of the " standard one. That's a problem for sure. I replaced all ” with " in your code and copied a sample image and it worked! I did it with dev tools so not very easy to test, but I think this will solve it.

Comment: Replaced the double quotes and it's working right now as it should. 
Thank you for your time!